# Wiping files found by PhotoRec

Tags: security, data-recovery, privacy

After running PhotoRec, the report.xml file gives a summary of every file that could potentially be restored from my hard disk, for example:

```
  <fileobject>
    <filename>/place/recup_dir.2/f1234567.png</filename>
    <filesize>47944</filesize>
    <byte_runs>
      <byte_run offset='0' img_offset='825906883201' len='49120'/>
    </byte_runs>
  </fileobject>
```

Is there any possibility to use these data to specifically wipe the original files from the free space of my hard disk, so it won't be able to restore the file?

Use case: I forgot to wipe a sensitive file that should not be recovered.

Thank you!